# Exchange Local Mail Queue Time Kept

Tags: exchange-2003, queue, disaster

We had a massive exchange information store failure, and the exchange mail queue was filling up with emails for over a week. When I look in the queue now, I only see emails queued for the last few days.

Question is, how long does exchange keep mails in the queue, and is this configurable?

If they are removed from the queue due to a timeout, do they go somewhere, or just deleted?

Where in the filesystem can I actually see this data? I can only see it via exchange system manager.

(Exchange 2003)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default the SMTP virtual server in Exchange has a message expiration setting of 2 days (48 hours). When the expiration time is met the messages are deleted from the queues. As far as I'm aware there's no file system interface for the outbound email queues.

Here's a nice article on mail flow through Exchange:

http://www.msexchange.org/tutorials/Exchange-Server-2003-Mailflow-Part1.html

Comment: Actually, you can view the messages in the queue on the file system.  On my server it's located at C:\Program Files\Exchsrvr\Mailroot\vsi 1\Queue

Comment: That's for incoming SMTP messages from the internet, not for outgoing messages from MAPI clients. Outgoing messages from MAPI clients are submitted to the message store, not the SMTP queues.

Comment: Ah, did not realize that.  Thanks for the clarification.